# iPhone how to: Develop app that alerts you on call time

Tags: iphone, timer, background, call, core-telephony

Is there any way that I can develop an application that is running in the background that will detect when a call is being made, start a timer and then alert me at any set time, say before 5 minutes?.

I used to do a lot of iPhone programming but I haven't done any in 6 months. Is there any way to do this now?. Can anyone point me in the right direction?. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `callEventHandler` in CoreTelephony. It's not exactly what you want, but read the discussion carefully. You'll be able to use this to do what you want in some cases. If your app is available for full blown background multitasking, then using it might even be reliable.

Comment: What determines if my app is available for full blown background multitasking?

Comment: There are a finite set of applications (VoIP, Audio, Location) that are allowed to run in the background. Everything else is capable of running a task in the background for no more than 10 minutes from the time the app transitioned to the background. However, normal apps get suspended still.